# Prove the formula RMS = 2.22*average of for a half-wave rectified sinusoid with a zero average value?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rms

I was wondering if anyone can clarify exactly how I am supposed to prove the formula above. If I try to verify my work as I have gotten, then I would have sqrt(2)/2 = 2/pi*2.22 which is not the case; though, I may have easily made a mistake since I see that if either side is doubled or halved respectively, then the formula essentially works out. Also, I do not understand what the question implies by a half-wave rectified sinusoid with a zero average value. I assumed that it was not zero, because otherwise, then, in order to prove the statement, the RMS would have to be zero in such a case, which is a bit too straightforward. Unless, of course, I am mistaken. I have attached my work for reference. I truly appreciate any help!

EDIT: I have attached some useful information that may be ideal to understanding the idea of what "average" means in this case, so that may be a part of the solution.

EDIT 2: I realize now that if I truly wanted a half-wave rectified sine wave, then the period would actually be T, but as for the sine function integral, it would be 0 to T/2. Thus, the average value would be 1/pi, and the RMS value would be 0.5. My question then becomes, why is it that the only way for the RMS to be 2.22 times the average value, I would have to compare the whole sine wave RMS value to the average value of a half-wave rectified sine wave? Otherwise, it makes sense. sqrt(2)/2/(1/pi) = 2.22 roughly.

EDIT 3: I have removed the refereince image, just to clarify that my work is shown right after the question below this statement. My work starts at "RMS Voltage = " and "Average Voltage = "; the question has already been answered thankfully, but in case people are getting the wrong idea, as was stated in a similarly formated second question of mine, hopefully this clarifies it.

[image]

For reference information for the question, see this image, (I am not posting it directly, because otherwise people think that both my work and this reference are just copied from some source.)
http://puu.sh/inVZn/f599f78f6e.png

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is badly phrased. The value 2.2 is correct when comparing the average of a half-wave rectified sine with the RMS of either a full-wave rectified sine or the unrectified sine. The RMS of a half-wave rectified sine wave is sqrt(2)/4.